# Variables and aliases with Python's code.interact

Tags: python

This behavior has me puzzled:

```
import code

class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def interact(self):
        v = globals()
        v.update(vars(self))
        code.interact(local=v)

c = foo()
c.interact()

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23) 
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> id(x)
29082424
>>> id(c.x)
29082424
>>> x
1
>>> c.x
1
>>> x=2
>>> c.x
1
```

Why doesn't 'c.x' behave like an alias for 'x'?  If I understand the id() function correctly, they are both at the same memory address.

Comment: Try calling `id(x)` after reassigning it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small integers from from -5 to 256 are cached in python, i.e their `id()` is always going to be same.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1            #same id() here as integer 1 is cached by python.
>>> x is y
True
```

## Update:

> If two identifiers return same value of **id()** then it doesn't mean they can act as alias of
>   each other, it totally depends on the type of the object they are pointing to.

For **immutable** object you cannot create alias in python. Modifying one of the reference to an immutable object will simple make it point to a new object, while other references to that older object will still remain intact.

```
>>> x = y = 300
>>> x is y        # x and y point to the same object
True
>>> x += 1        # modify x
>>> x             #  x now points to a different object 
301
>>> y             #y still points to the old object
300
```

A **mutable** object can be modified from any of it's references, but those modifications must be in-place modifications.

```
>>> x = y = []
>>> x is y
True
>>> x.append(1)   # list.extend is an in-place operation
>>> y.append(2)   # in-place operation 
>>> x
[1, 2]
>>> y             #works fine so far
[1, 2]

>>> x = x + [1]   #not an in-place operation
>>> x
[1, 2, 1]          #assigns a new object to x
>>> y              #y still points to the same old object
[1, 2]
```

Comment: the sentence "For mutable objects you can create alias" is technically incorrect, and I believe you know it. Maybe "they may behave in a way similar to that of an alias".

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  The mutable vs non-mutable object concept is what I was missing.  The id() confusion was just a side show.

Answer (score 2):

> If I understand the id() function correctly, they are both at the same memory address.

You don't understand it correctly. `id` returns an integer in respect of which the following identity is guaranteed: if `id(x) == id(y)` then `x is y` is guaranteed (and vice versa).

Accordingly, `id` tells you about the objects (values) that variables point to, not about the variables themselves.

Any relationship to memory addresses is purely an implementation detail. Python, unlike, e.g. C, does not assume any particular relationship to the underlying machine (whether physical or virtual). Variables in python are both opaque, and not language accessible (i.e. not first class).

Comment: But it is a well documented implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: @Elazar So? It doesn't actually help you.

Comment: Nor it is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Elazar Apart from the misconception about what `id` provides appearing in the question, that is.

Comment: I am not saying that you don't answer the question. Only that the issue of whether or not it is guaranteed to be a memory address is irrelevant.

Comment: @Elazar It's relevant, because it goes to a fundamental misunderstanding of how python works.

Comment: The whole `id` confusion is.

Answer (score 2):

`code.interact` simply did (effectively) `x=c.x` for you. So when you checked their `id`s, they were pointing to the exact same object. But `x=2` creates a new binding for the variable `x`. It is not an alias. Python does not have aliases, as far as I am aware.

Yes, in CPython `id(x)` is the memory address of the object `x` points to. It is *not* the memory address of the variable `x` itself (which is, after all, just a key in a dictionary).